# HTML5 Video - Auto select correct resolution

Tags: html5-video

I'm working on a page that has a list of houses for sale. Each listing has a short video with the option of watching in the page or full screen.

I'm struggling a little with having the videos on the page at one resolution and the fullscreen at a higher resolution - this is needed especially for devices that automatically go fullscreen when the play icon is pressed.

I've had good results with video.js (http://www.videojs.com/) for the page resolution but it doesn't appear to support resolution change on fullscreen. I found this thread with comments about the HTML spec and changing resolution mid-stream: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/233.

I'm told the embedded Youtube player selects the correct resolution automatically but the branded player makes this a non-starter.

Also I've found that in IE10 without Flash that the embedded Vimeo player doesn't function and in Chrome without Flash the Vimeo and Youtube players fail as well... so much for HTML5!

So anyone have a solution for showing video at the correct resolution (low/high) for the state of the player (contained/fullscreen)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question answered a query of mine. It looks like auto switching resolution is still not implemented in videoJS other than for YouTube videos. There is a demo at [videoJS Resolution Switcher](https://kmoskwiak.github.io/videojs-resolution-switcher/) and you can see in the console that changing window resolution to full screen has no effect.

I've been using the [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/) for several years with no problems at all. It reliably supports auto switching has many features and very good support.